# Registering all exceptions from rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monitoring

I have in some applications a custom library that gathers sensitive information.

This information comes from various sites, like: Twitter, Facebook, governamental blogs, college sites and common blogs.

I created a parser for each source because some of them are not well written and some of them need some hard coded parsing (regexp and stuff).

Everything worked fine. A few days ago I saw in my monitoring tool some exeptions on the client side. when I went looking for it I discovered that one of my "watched" sites had changed their HTML+CSS so I had to reimplement the parser for that website.

So this made me think, what would happen if others sites also changed their markup?

So I did all my parsers raise custom exeptions for my monitor to log. But when it comes to ruby I know I can do something more elaborated.

My question is: Is there a way to catch all exceptions in my application, adding custom behaviour, like a before filter, and letting the others trigger their default actions?

To illustrate:

I have in my twitter parser this exception if i got a parser error: `raise Twitter::ParserError`

somewhere, inside a initializer or something, i have this register (this is what i want):

```
# after 5 exceptions of Twitter::ParserError i want to act
registerException(Twitter::ParserError, 5.times) do
  # Send me an email warning me about this error
  # or do something with my environment
  # Parser.find_by_website(website: :twitter).report_offline
end
```

Comment: This depends on how much control over the app you have. If you can't just surround the app with a begin, rescue, end,the solution is not going to be pretty.

Comment: won't surrounding my app with a ``begin rescue`` remove **ALL** exceptions?

Comment: Not if you selectively rethrow exceptions you don't want to catch.

Comment: Why do you need at least 5 exceptions? Does it mean that you don't care for first 4?

Comment: @IvanShamatov this is like: after the 5 cast of that exception i want to be alarmed. something like: hey, this is getting serious now...

Answer (score 0):

I won't comment on whether I think this is the right approach to this problem... but this was a fun little metaprogramming challenge.

The thing to realize is that `raise`, like most things in ruby, is just a method. So you can alias method chain it and do whatever you want before or after calling the original, giving you effectively a "before" and "after" hook on the raising of methods.

Here's an implementation of your pseudo code above. The one thing you DON'T get with this is a handle on the actual instance of the exception being raised, so you couldn't, for example, include a stack trace in the email sent to you. I'm not sure if there would be a way to get your hands on that exception, since the creation of it is in C code.

But here you go:

```
module Kernel
  @@registered_exceptions ||= {}
  @@raises ||= {}

  def register_exception(exception_class, times = 5, &block)
    @@registered_exceptions[exception_class] = {
      times: times,
      block: block
    }
  end

  alias_method :original_raise, :raise
  def hacked_raise(*args)
    # figure out what class we are about to `raise`
    # see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-raise
    # about why this is the correct logic.
    exception_class = if args.empty?
                        if $!
                          $!.class
                        else
                          RuntimeError
                        end
                      elsif args[0].is_a? String
                        RuntimeError
                      else
                        args[0]
                      end

    # this exception is not registered so forget it and act normally
    (original_raise(*args) and return) unless @@registered_exceptions.keys.include?(exception_class)



    @@raises[exception_class] ||= 0
    @@raises[exception_class] += 1

    if @@raises[exception_class] == @@registered_exceptions[exception_class][:times]
      @@raises[exception_class] = 0 # reset counter for this exception class
      @@registered_exceptions[exception_class][:block].call
    end
  end
  alias_method :raise, :hacked_raise
end

register_exception RuntimeError, 3 do
  puts "hey, there were 3 runtime exceptions raised!"
end

raise
raise
raise
raise
raise
raise
raise
```